# Error unexpected null value

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml

tengo un error al colocar las imágenes en flutter, he intentado varias maneras pero no logro encontrar cual es el error.

```
  OnboardContent(
    image: "assets/images/axiet.jpg",
    text: "A veces es difícil, más no imposible",
    descripcion:
        "Todas tus preocupaciones tienen una solución.",
  ),
];
```

He colocado bien la dirección de imagen.
En pubspec.yaml

```
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
```

Al ejecutar aparece así:

[image: Al ejecutar aparece así]

*Error en consola*

````
═╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unexpected null value.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 606:63  nullCheck
packages/flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart 856:29                          _loadAsync
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1660:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 584:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 657:7                                         callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 177:15               <fn>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/main_top.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#758c5(), name: 
  "assets/images/main_top.png", scale: 1)```
````

Comment: Perdón por la pregunta tonta, pero: ¿la imagen existe y tiene exactamente ese nombre?

Comment: La consola suele arrojar información sobre el error, debería poner el error o información que muestra. Por otro lado, ¿cómo está construido el widget OnboardContent?

Comment: Ya he editado y puse el error que sale en la consola 

@Manuel

Comment: @Alfabravo
La imagen si existe y tiene ese nombre

Comment: El error no menciona la imagen que has posteado, sino una llamada main_top. Deberías investigar eso primero.

Comment: En un principio el error se produce por otra imagen que al parecer has utilizado en otra parte de tu proyecto, asegurate de revisar la carpeta "images" y que exista un archivo con el nombre "main_top". Puede que el nombre no sea el mismo o simplemente el archivo con ese nombre no existe en esa carpeta.